# jq: how to filter nested keys?

Tags: json, jq

I have done a lot of research on stackoverflow but cannot find any related post.

assume I have a json like

```
{
    "talk": {
        "docs": {
            "count": 22038185,
            "deleted": 626193
        },
        "store": {
            "size_in_bytes": 6885993125,
            "throttle_time_in_millis": 1836569
        }
    },
    "list": {
        "docs": {
            "count": 22038185,
            "deleted": 626193
        },
        "store": {
            "size_in_bytes": 6885993125,
            "throttle_time_in_millis": 1836569
        }
    }
}
```

I want to filter out "store" field in all keys to get an output like

```
{
    "talk": {
        "docs": {
            "count": 22038185,
            "deleted": 626193
        }
    },
    "list": {
        "docs": {
            "count": 22038185,
            "deleted": 626193
        }
    }
}
```

How can I achieve it with jq?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only want to remove the "store" key when it occurs at the second level, then consider:

```
map_values( del(.store) )
```

#### Postscript

Subsequently, the OP asked:

> But what if the deleted fields are many? can we only keep 'docs'

Answer (in this particular case):

```
map_values( {docs} )
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `del` and `recurse` together.

```
jq 'del(recurse|.store?)' foo.json
```

You can also the short `..` for `recurse` with no arguments:

```
jq 'del(..|.store?)' foo.json
```

The `?` prevents errors when `recurse` reaches something for which `.store` is an invalid filter.

Comment: this is great. But what if the deleted fields are many? can we only keep 'docs'

Comment: That's a different question.